# search mysql in comma list

Tags: php, sql

in my database there is cat_id that is filled by comma list like 2,5,12. but unfortunately when I want execute query like WHERE cat_id='2,5,12' there is no result.

```
SELECT * FROM `site_content` WHERE `status`!='deleted' AND `cat_id` ='4,6,14'
```

is there any problem in comma?

Comment: So there are multiple category IDs in a comma-separated list? Or just one category ID and you want to look up several?

Comment: it is id field that is created from multiple id

Comment: if cat_id value is '4,6,14', your code should work. If cat_id value can be '4,14,6', it does not work. For example, if cat_id values are '4,6,14', '4,6,14,15',  '4,14,6', which ones should be selected by your query?

Comment: No my code is  '4,6,14' exactly

Comment: Then your code should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code and it is working.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/790ff/2/0

What is your schema of table?

Answer (score 1):

This may help..

```
SELECT * FROM site_content WHERE status!='deleted' AND cat_id IN ('4','6','14')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like

```
SELECT * FROM site_content WHERE status!='deleted' AND cat_id IN (4,6,14)
```

Comment: can you tell me reason so i can help

Answer (score 0):

```
$cat = "4,6,14";

$arr = explode(",",$cat);

for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site_content WHERE status!='deleted' AND cat_id ='".$arr[$i]."'");


}
```

Comment: No I want to search in cat_id completely not separably